# Структуры с необязательными эллемнтами

Tags: c++

Задача: создать структуру "студент", содержащую в себе его стипендию.
Тут я вас попрошу помочь мне реализовать МОЙ алгоритм, а не предлагать свой для решения задачи.
Итак, предположим, что есть 3 вида стипендии - A, B , C. 
У каждой стипендии сумма выплат равна константе, но при частных случаях эту сумму можно изменять. Имя стипендии так же является константой. Моя попытка реализации #1
Предполагается, что amount и name - необязательные элементы. По моей идее, они должны определяться в зависимости от id, если только их не задавать.

```
int step_amounts[3] = {1000, 3000, 5000};
string step_names[3] = {"A", "B", "C"};

struct Stependy {short id; int* amount = &step_amounts[id-1]; string* name=&step_names[id-1];};
struct Student {string fname;string sname; Stependy stependy;};


int main()
{
    Student student;
    student.stependy.id=1;
    cout << *(student.stependy.amount) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Но вот незадача, amount и name инициилизируются при инициализации student сразу, а не при определении id. И что делать? Как задать необязательный параметр, который зависит от предыдущих параметров?
Еще одна попытка, которая, конечно не сработала. Но я хотя бы покажу, что я хочу сделать :c

```
int step_amounts[3] = {1000, 3000, 5000};
string step_names[3] = {"A", "B", "C"};

struct Stependy {short id; int* amount; string* name;};
struct Student {string fname;string sname;
 Stependy getStependy(short id, int* amount = &step_amounts[id-1], string* name=&step_names[id-1]){
 return {id, amount, name}};};


int main()
{
    Student student = {"X","Y",(1)};
    cout << *(student.stependy.amount) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста , хочется сделать всё максимально красиво :(

UDP:
Пришла в голову идея, но не хватает знания, как обратиться к структуре-владельцу через дочернюю структуру. В коде ниже я обратился напрямую, что, логично не сработало.

```
int step_amounts[3] = {1000, 3000, 5000};
string step_names[3] = {"A", "B", "C"};

struct Stependy {int* amount=step_amounts[Student.stepid-1]; string* name=step_names[Student.stepid-1];};
struct Student {string fname;string sname; short stepid; Stependy stependy};

int main()
{
    Student student = {"X","Y",1, {}};
    cout << *(student.stependy.amount) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ничего тут не поделать. Язык такой

Comment: "amount и name инициилизируются при инициализации student сразу"... Что значит "сразу"? Нет, конечно. Они инициализируются именно при создании объекта этого класса, вместе с `id`. Укажите другие инициализаторы в конструкторе - и они будут другие. Зачем вы вообще взялись указывать инициализаторы прямо в определении класса? Что это за странная манера, пользоваться этой относительно новой фичей языка по поводу и без повода?

Comment: AnT, чтож, я это и имел ввиду. Простите мою неграмотность. Взялся я это делать, потому что категорически не понимаю, как сделать иначе

Comment: @AnT, а чем фича плоха?

Comment: @avp, а с языком что не так? Вроде всё описанное получается довольно легко и даже без извращений.

Comment: @Qwertiy, с крестами? Все не так. Слишком много всего и часто слишком сложно. В результате многие не понимают чужой код.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: Плохого в ней ничего нет. Просто много молодежи бросилось ее использовать без понимания того факта, что такие инициализаторы - фича особая. Они задают лишь будущий план инициализации, который будет физически реализовываться совсем в другом месте - в конструкторе класса. И даже там у пользователя еще есть возможность перекрыть этот план.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого предназначены конструкторы: https://ideone.com/gqB3Fe

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int step_amounts[3] = {1000, 3000, 5000};
string step_names[3] = {"A", "B", "C"};

struct Stependy
{
  short id;
  int &amount;
  string &name;

  Stependy(short id) : id(id), amount(step_amounts[id-1]), name(step_names[id-1]) {}
};

struct Student
{
  string fname;
  string sname;
  Stependy stependy;

  Student(string fname, string sname, short s) : fname(fname), sname(sname), stependy(s) {}
};


int main()
{
  Student student("Abc", "Def", 2);
  cout << student.stependy.amount << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Если ссылочная связь с массивом не требуется, то следует отказаться от ссылок.

Также можно настроить прокидывание параметров с конструктор стипендии из студента: https://ideone.com/9vidoS

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int step_amounts[3] = {1000, 3000, 5000};
string step_names[3] = {"A", "B", "C"};

struct Stependy
{
  short id;
  int amount;
  string name;

  Stependy(short id)
  : id(id), amount(step_amounts[id-1]), name(step_names[id-1])
  {}

  Stependy(short id, int amount)
  : id(id), amount(amount), name(step_names[id-1])
  {}

  Stependy(short id, int amount, string name)
  : id(id), amount(amount), name(name)
  {}
};

struct Student
{
  string fname;
  string sname;
  Stependy stependy;

  template <typename ...S>
  Student(string fname, string sname, S &&...s)
  : fname(fname), sname(sname), stependy(forward<S>(s)...)
  {}
};


int main()
{
  Student students[] = 
  {
    Student("Abc", "Def", 2),
    Student("Aaa", "Ddd", 2, 2000),
    Student("Bbb", "Eee", 2, 4000, "other"),
    Student("Ccc", "Fff", 4, 7000, "qqq")
  };

  for (auto st : students)
    cout << st.fname << ' ' << st.sname << ' ' << st.stependy.id << ' ' << st.stependy.amount << ' ' << st.stependy.name << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @loverx, это конструктор. Конкретно название для двоеточий не помню. У тебя были указатели, я заменил их на ссылки, но в обоих случаях при попытке записать в `student.stependy.amount` (что возможно) значение изменится в массиве `step_amounts`. Я считал, что это желаемое поведение - если это не так, то убери ссылки из объявлений.

Comment: мы можем обсудить это лично, дабы не засорять комментарии? после решения опубликую его тут.

Comment: Блин.. Сколько возни, чтобы руками создать чат... Заходи: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99639/. Только я на часок отойду, потом отвечу.

Answer (score 1):

Держать глобальные массивы плохо, особенно, что они предназначены лишь для реализации структуры.  Плюс, вместо двух массивов и одной структуры `Stependy` , для вашего случая, можно иметь один массив  типа  перечисления `Stependy`.  И, чтобы массив не принадлежал структуре, сделать его статическим. Значит, я предлогаю так:

```
struct Student { 
    enum  Stependy { A = 1000, B = 3000, C = 5000};
    static Stependy stependy[3];
    string fname{};
    string sname{};
    short id{1};
    Stependy amount = stependy[id - 1]; 
};
Student::Stependy
Student::stependy[3] = { Stependy::A, Stependy::B, Stependy::C };
int main()
{   
    Student student = { "X","Y", 2};
    cout << student.amount << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Хотя, если подумать, то член   `id` совершенно лишный, и все будет выглядеть лучше без него. Так можно убрать статический массив, который нарушал безопасность кода(при отсутствии конструктора и инкапсуляции id), и код будет выглядеть понятней(указываем какой тип степендии назначаем):

```
struct Student { 
   enum  Stependy { A = 1000, B = 3000, C = 5000};  
   string fname{};
   string sname{};  
   Stependy amount = A; 
};

int main()
{   
    Student student1 = { "X","Y", Student::Stependy::B },
            student2 = { "MY", "Name" };
    cout << student1.amount << endl << student2.amount; 
    return 0;
}
```