# В чём смысл std::forward при передаче параметров?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, ссылки, параметры

В чём разница между следующими двумя способами передачи параметров?

```
template <typename ...Args> smth(Args &&...args) : base(args...) {}
```

```
template <typename ...Args> smth(Args &&...args) : base(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
```

Comment: Наверное все таки `std::forward<Args>(args)...`

Comment: вопрос придуман от скуки?...Сейчас   AnT напишет статью

Comment: @AnT, да, точно. Забыл указать.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, неа. [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1032543/178988) написал без forward - вроде работает, а пока искал точный синтаксис (несколько попутал, в каком порядке амперсанды, многоточия и переменную надо писать), попалась версия с forward. Но что он даёт, я что-то не понял - вроде ж и так работает...

Comment: @Qwertiy, без std::forward компилятор предпологает, что вы передаете аргументы по ссыльке, и ели у base есть и конструктор перемещения, то  будет работать конструктор копирования, т.е. пересылать туда не получится. С std::forward  компилятор сохранит "rvalue ness"  и переместит содержимо аргументов, после чего оригиналы окажутся пустыми

Comment: По-моему тема уже освещалась: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908361/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-move-%D0%B8-forward

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Предположим, что конструктор `base` принимает move-only параметр по значению:

```
struct base {
  base(std::unique_ptr<int> value);
};
```

В таком случае первый вариант не скомпилируется:

```
template <typename ...Args> smth(Args &&...args) : base(args...) {}
                                  попытка сделать копию ^^^^
```

Тут можно написать `std::move` и это будет работать:

```
template <typename ...Args> smth(Args &&...args) : base(std::move(args)...) {}
```

---

Однако в случае если у `base` два конструктора, один из которых перемещает значение, а другой принимает ссылку:

```
struct base {
  base(std::unique_ptr<int>&& value);
  base(std::unique_ptr<int>& value);
};
```

И если мы хотим чтобы `smth` передавал в `base` именно те типы аргументов, с которыми его вызвали, то `std::move` нам не подойдет - он всегда будет превращать аргумент в r-value ссылку.

Для этого есть `std::forward<T>`, который сохраняет оригинальный тип аргумента:

```
struct smth : base {
  template <typename ...Args> smth(Args &&...args) : base(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};

std::unique_ptr<int> p;
smth s1(p);            // OK, будет вызван base(std::unique_ptr<int>&);
smth s2(st::move(p));  // OK, будет вызван base(std::unique_ptr<int>&&);
```

---

Примечание: `std::forward<T>(t)` работает только с "универсальнами ссылками", т.е. когда `T` - это параметр шаблона функции (конструктора), а `t` - аргумент этой функции с типом `T&&` (это специальное исключение в языке, такой тип `T&&` не является r-value ссылкой, а заставляет `T` повторять тип того, что передали в функцию).